# rows to columns in sql (not all the rows)

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

i am trying convert the row data into column in SQL, here is the data i have in my table

```
ID  NAME   DATE      STATUS
1    A     1/1/15     START
1    A     1/20/15     END
```

I want result as

```
ID  NAME START_DATE  END_DATE
1     A    1/1/15     1/20/15
```

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: SELECT ID,NAME, MAX(CASE WHEN STATUS='START' THEN DATE END) ,MAX(CASE WHEN STATUS='END' THEN DATE END) FROM T GROUP BY ID ,NAME

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out Pivot.. Seems to be what you are looking to do.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx